# How can i get minimum and maximum latitude and longitude using current location and radius?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I want Minimum and Maximum Latitude and Longitude Using Current Location.Suppose i have give the area of 20km so using that latitude and Longitude i want Maximum latitude and Longitude and Minimum latitude and Longitude also want all latitude and Longitude in between this so how can i get it.How can i use of radius in it.Please help me.Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can manually calculate it... I don't know if any other way exist 
1° latitude = 69.047 statute miles = 60 nautical miles
= 111.12 kilometers

so for 20 kilometers it would be around 0.18 latitude 
For longitude the conversion is the same as latitude except the value is multiplied by the cosine of the latitude.

To set the same range on map for display

```
newRegion.center=newLocation.coordinate;
    //  newRegion.span.latitudeDelta = (20*2)/111.12;   // For kilometers

    newRegion.span.latitudeDelta = (20*2)/60.0; // For Miles
    newRegion.span.longitudeDelta = ((20*2)/60.0) *(cos(newRegion.span.latitudeDelta)); // For Miles
    mapView.region = newRegion;
```

It will set 20 kilometer's range on map that is displayed...

so you can find it by

you can find it by

```
minLattitude = currentLattitude - (RadiusInKm/111.12);
maxLattitude = currentLattitude + (RadiusInKm/111.12);
```

For longitude same but multiply the result with cosine of latitude...

Comment: i have current location and radius now i want to find Min Lat/Long and  
Max Lat/Long (region) how can i find this...

Comment: Hi Ankit,
you can find it by 
minLattitude = currentLattitude - (RadiusInKm/111.12);
maxLattitude = currentLattitude + (RadiusInKm/111.12);

For logitude same but multiply the result with cosine of lattitude...I am updating the same in answer...

Comment: double minLattitude,maxLattitude,minLongitude,maxLongitude;

minLattitude = self.currentLocation.latitude - ((LOCATE_PIN_MILE*1.609344)/111.12);
minLongitude = self.currentLocation.longitude * cos(minLattitude);
 
maxLattitude = self.currentLocation.latitude + ((LOCATE_PIN_MILE*1.609344)/111.12);
maxLongitude = self.currentLocation.longitude * cos(maxLattitude);

Is it ok?
Where LOCATE_PIN_MILE is in miles.
I am not getting correct results.
Please suggest me.

Comment: use LOCATE_PIN_MILE/60 direct OR LOCATE_PIN_MILE*2/60... one of them should be work

Comment: rad = 1Km  , location = 41.650476 -0.872905   result: Mlat41.659475 mLon0.596298 mLat41.641477 MLon0.607675 . So, It is not work as a  a general solution

Answer (score 0):

1) Macros to convert Degrees to Radians:

```
#define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(degrees) (degrees / 180.0 * M_PI)
```

2) Macros to raduis in KM:

```
#define radiusInKM 5.00
```

3) Set the minimum and maximum Latitude, Longitude values

```
CLLocation *location;//your current location

1° latitude = 69.047 statute miles = 60 nautical miles = 111.12 kilometers

double minLat = location.coordinate.latitude - (radiusInKM/111.12);

double maxLat = location.coordinate.latitude + (radiusInKM/111.12);

double minLon = location.coordinate.longitude - (radiusInKM) / fabs(cos(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(location.coordinate.longitude))*111.12);

double maxLon = location.coordinate.longitude + (radiusInKM) / fabs(cos(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(location.coordinate.longitude))*111.12);
```

Answer (score -1):

1. macros to convert Degrees to Radians

   ## define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(degrees) (degrees / 180.0 * M_PI)
2. macros to raduis in KM

   ## define radiusInKM 5.00
3. set the minimum and maximum Latitude, Longitude values

   CLLocation *location;//your current location

   1° latitude = 69.047 statute miles = 60 nautical miles = 111.12 kilometers

   double minLat = location.coordinate.latitude - (radiusInKM/111.12);

   double maxLat = location.coordinate.latitude +   (radiusInKM/111.12);

   double minLon = location.coordinate.longitude - (radiusInKM) / fabs(cos(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(location.coordinate.longitude))*111.12);

   double maxLon = location.coordinate.longitude + (radiusInKM) / fabs(cos(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(location.coordinate.longitude))*111.12);

Comment: Not sure how this is substantially different from the accepted answer, but at least delete one of your answers