# Find Minimum and Maximum - latitude and Longitude for search

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

My question is how can I find the minimum and maximum latitude and longitude of a specific area (150 miles) from the current location in one line of code in c#.

my case:- my lat/long is a/b and other lat/long is x/y and my search radius is 150 miles. I want to check x/y is in my search radius or not

I also have to try googling and I got link such like

[Find Minimum/Maximum latitude and Longitude](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18696441/6375065)

But I don't know how it implements in my case.

Comment: Why does it have to be in one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is fairly straightforward to write a loop to get both minimum and maximum in each direction

```
    public static (LatLong min, LatLong max) MinMax(IEnumerable<LatLong> points)
    {
        using (var iter = points.GetEnumerator())
        {

            if (!iter.MoveNext())
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("No coordinates");
            }

            var min = iter.Current;
            var max = iter.Current;
            while (iter.MoveNext())
            {
                min = min.Min(iter.Current);
                max = max.Max(iter.Current);
            }

            return (min, max);
        }
    }
```

where Min/Max returns the minimum/maximum value for each component of the two coordinates.

Comment: I can't test it right now but thank for help i'll update answer when i test this thanks @JonasH