# Find min and max latitude and longitude in java from given latitude , longitude and radius values

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

I can find the distance from latitude and longitude (i.e; minLatitude,minLongitude,maxLatitude and maxLongitude respectively) but I need sample java code to find minLatitude, minLongitude, maxLatitude and maxLongitude from input latitude , longitude and radius values.

Here is the code for finding distance from lat1 , long1, lat2 and lang2 values.

```
public static double distance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
        double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
        double dLon = Math.toRadians(lon2 - lon1);
        lat1 = Math.toRadians(lat1);
        lat2 = Math.toRadians(lat2);

        double a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) + Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2);
    double c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
    return R * c;
}
```

Comment: Although in another programming language, I think [this might help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3067597/1300817) as it achieves the same thing, and the code is kinda straightforward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like:

```
/** returns minLatitude, maxLatitude, minLongitude, maxLongitude */
public double[] calculateMinMaxValues(double latitude , double longitude, double radius){
    double[] res = new double[4];
    res[0] /*minLatitude*/ = latitude - (radius*2)/60.0;
    res[1] /*maxLatitude*/ = latitude + (radius*2)/60.0;

    res[2] /*minLongitude*/ = (longitude*2)/60.0 *(Math.cos(res[0]));
    res[3] /*maxLongitude*/ = (longitude*2)/60.0 *(Math.cos(res[1]));
    return res;
}
```